# Can I use a 295 amp welder with a 7.5kW generator by changing the welder's plug?

Tags: welding

I have a $295 amp Emerson electric welder and it's got a three-prong on it big three prongs I have a generator it's 7500 series Pacific equipment can I change the welder plug to fit the three prong that goes into the generator

Comment: What is $295 amp

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you post the precise model number of your generator + a photo of your welder's nameplate please?

Comment: This isn't making a lot of sense. 295 Amps seems an awful lot of power, and wanting to change the outlet (?) is quite drastic. Best to ask directly the manufacturer, and if it's new, they'll tell you the guarantee will be invalidated at least. And, if you need to ask this sort of question, it would appear you're not the guy to do the job!

Comment: So your question is that you want to run your 295 amp, ( or 295 dollar) welder from your generator, but need to cut off the welders plug and make it smaller to be able to plug into the generator?   My guess is...NO.

Comment: While we are missing many details, commenters should be aware than an arc welder uses a transformer to provide high current at low voltage - a 295A welder might only require 50A@240V **input** - and might work fine on fewer amps input (small generator) at lower output settings (295A is not a range used much in typical arc welding, however, one that will go there is less limited in the 70-150A range more commonly used than a smaller unit (the 180A output 30A input being typical.)

Comment: So I should change my guess to ...yes?

Comment: The Magic 8-Ball says: "Signs point to more details needed from the questioner."

Answer (score 1):

Rather than modifying your welder cord, simply make an adapter cord (one end plugs into the generator, with that proper plug - the other end has the proper receptacle for your welder's plug.)

Not nearly enough detail (yet) to tell if this will work with the two machines in question, but you won't have ruined your welder's cord to suit a probably temporary arrangement, so it will still be able to be plugged into the correct receptacle for full performance when needed.

Comment: That generator has a 6kW socket.  Re "full performance" would >6kW power consumption be a feature of a <$300 welder?  I have never bought one.  I'm optimistic about this answer.

Comment: The $ is likely a mistake. Emerson Electric made a 295A (@20% duty cycle) "buzz-box" that was also rebadged by Sears and Montgomery Wards (at least) which will operate at 100% duty cycle up to something like 120A output. "Full performance" would, indeed, be more than 6KW input. And it may have cost less than $200 (in 1980's dollars)

Comment: The "big plug" might be there to ensure it isn't plugged into a lower-amperage circuit...?

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  So if it's like [this one](https://www.ebay.com/itm/134036877954) where the seller has clearly posted the nameplate, it wants 15kW supply so you could run it at maybe 35% capacity.  Seems like the money spent on your proposed cord would be better spent on a small used welder.

Comment: A "large welder" can be turned down. A small welder cannot be turned up. Input current is proportional to output, and the big welder can weld all day long without needing a cool-down break - plus, questioner already has the bigger welder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your welder is badged for 240V 60A power supply, as I have found similar models on line.

Your generator has a 25A socket.  Rather than rigging up a way to run the welder at only 40% capacity (or in reality probably less if you don't want to pop breakers or create brownouts) my advice would be to buy a smaller, used welder that will work without modification and without stressing the generator.